# Benefits of using SmallAutoField as primary key in Django?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, primary-key

My table will have around 2000 rows.

Are there any performance benefits to using SmallAutoField as the primary key rather than the standard AutoField?

Also, if in the future I run out of the 32,000 incrementing integers in my SmallAutoField, how difficult would it be to change it to a regular AutoField?

PS. I am using SQLite but may switch to Postgres.

Comment: At that size it's unlikely performance concerns would be an issue. If there is even a slim chance you will run out of primary keys, then go with AutoField/Serial rather than prematurely optimize.  Table usage changes and people are generally bad at anticipating future table size.

Comment: You're currently working with SQLite, that means you have basically no serious performance requirements. Then don't worry about some extra bytes that are needed for an integer. 32000 id's for a smallint would take about 62KB, for an integer it would take 124KB. 40 years ago that would have been a large difference, nowadays nobody should care. Our main database is about 4TB in size.

Comment: @FrankHeikens its apparently a recent feature from Django. I wonder why they implemented it then. Will it have performance benefits if the table is actively used?